# R rgl - does rgl device require some sort of initialization before quads3d() will produce something visible?

Tags: r, rgl

I'm in current versions of RStudio, R, and rgl(.99.16) as of this writing.

It seems that `quads3d()` produces nothing visible until another object is displayed. For example, I do

```
  library(rgl)
  Face <- matrix(c(0,-.2,-.5,
                   .2,.2,-.5,
                   .2,.2,.5,
                   0,-.2,.5), nrow=4, byrow=T)
  open3d()
  quads3d(Face)
```

...and nothing appears in the RGL device. Face can be any set of 4 xyz coordinates.

However, if I say, for example,

```
  arrow3d(p0=c(0,0,0), p1=c(1,1,1))
```

(which successfully produces an arrow),

then subsequent executions of `quads3d(Face)` and other `quads3d()` statements do, in fact, successfully render the shape in the device. In general, under some environmental conditions which I haven't been able to pin down exactly (new rgl device plus empty workspace?) `quads3d()` generates nothing visible until another rgl statement is successfully executed.

Is there something I need to do to initialize an rgl device? How do I ensure that valid `quads3d()` with "good" data will consistently produce something in the rgl device?

Comment: Voting to close as a typo-equivalent.

Comment: It's not a typo, it is repeatable, and it was not addressed. But thanks for trying to vote me down. Feel free to reply if you think you can actually provide some valuable input.

Comment: I didn't vote down. Downvotes aren't particuarly useful in my opinion. Votes to close on the other hand are useful in flagging the quality of questions for future searchers. I just thought that the fact that the plot was in point of fact displaying the points meant that it was a basically trivial mistake, what I was calling a "typo-equivalent". Typos, after all, are repeatable as well, just not very useful. You have edited your question but have not yet explained what you were expecting to see and why. Plotting the arrow does not change the shape of the Face object.

Comment: Real simple: the first time I issue quad3d(with good args), nothing shows up. Subsequent to doing something, e.g., opening another device (but not always), drawing an arrow, I'm not sure exactly what, the identical command produces visible output in the same device without. My question is whether there's some initialization that has to be done that a straightforward quad3d() does not do.

Comment: So far no one else is seeing this problem on their box, so it still not reproducible except for your incompletely described setup. Your description is still missing R version, RStudio version, OS type and version, .... but since Rstudio is in the mix, you should also try in ordinary R.

Comment: OK, so I'll deduce from your comments that there's no initialization that I should need to do in order to display quad3d()'s. If it's going to display, it should display in the first rgl device I open the same as it displays in other rgl devices with identical parameters. Must be some other issue, so that answers my question. Thanks for your time. I'll delete this question shortly so it won't pollute the place any further.

Comment: @UncleFrank you can't (and should not) delete a question that has an answer with upvotes - see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/380687). Even if that answer is no longer of use to you, it may be to others in the future.

Answer (score 3):

Your original version in fact does render the face.  But the orientation is such that in the initial view it is seen end on and has zero width.

Rotate the view then you can see it

For example, try this:

```
Face <- matrix(c(0,-.2,-.5,
                 0,.2,-.5,
                 0,.2,.5,
                 0,-.2,.5), nrow=4, byrow=T)
open3d()
quads3d(Face)

play3d(spin3d(), duration = 5)
```

Comment: Sorry for the unfortunate example. This problem happens to me even when the initial viewing angle is not edge-on to a zero-dimension object. I just chose that one to try to be etiquette-compliant, which I apparently managed not to do anyhow. I can issue a series of 6 quad3d() commands describing a volumetric object with no possible ways to view it where it doesn't show by default. The first time I did this resulted in nothing being displayed. When I then opened another device and issued the same commands, the object displayed properly. So my question stands. Thanks

Comment: @UncleFrank Perhaps you need to specify versions (R and packages) as well as OS details. I think more than one of us (dww and me, anyway) are not seeing any anomalies, but without clear problem description there's no way to tell. (I'm doing this on a Linux box, R 3.5.1, rgl_0.99.16 .)